# Dylib compilation : Force linking to said dylibs

Tags: macos, shell, linker, dylib

On macOS Ventura, I am compiling dynamic libraries, depending on other dynamic libraries that I also compile.
On the other hand, other versions of these libraries are installed on my system via homebrew, so mostly in `/usr/local/lib`.

I want to link the libraries I compile between them, not to the one installed on my system, so my compile environment does not become system-dependent, and does not interfere with my system. The other reason is that I use `dylibbundler` when all the libraries are compiled to gather them and ready them for distribution inside my app.  So as they link to libs in `/usr/local/lib`, `dylibbundler` will take them from here (and no option allows me to force looking elsewhere first).

However, whatever I do, when I use `otool -l` on the dylibs I compiled, they always depend to the libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.

Note : I do want to link with the libraries I make, not to use `install_name_tool` to change their link after, because I want to be aware of any missing symbol when compiling, not at runtime with a weird bug.

---

Let's take the example of one of the libraries, libass, that depends on libharfbuzz and libfreetype, amongst others.

Here is the scripts I use to compile :

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
source ./prepare_each.sh
cd "[REDACTED]/libass"

./autogen.sh
make clean
./configure  --enable-coretext --enable-require-system-font-provider --enable-harfbuzz --with-sysroot=$BUILTDIR --libdir=$BUILTDIR
make

cp ./libass/.libs/*.dylib $BUILTDIR
```

`prepare_each.sh` being :

```bash
OSVER="10.13"
BUILTDIR="$HOME/lib"

mkdir $BUILTDIR

export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$OSVER
export CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$OSVER
export CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=$OSVER"
export CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=$OSVER"
export CPPFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=$OSVER"
export LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=$OSVER -L$BUILTDIR"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BUILTDIR
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BUILTDIR
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$BUILTDIR
export DYLD_VERSIONED_LIBRARY_PATH=$BUILTDIR
export LIBS=$BUILTDIR
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$BUILTDIR
```

As you can see, I have tried lots of ways to indicate the linker to link with libs in `BUILTDIR, but nothing changes. The minimum OS version, however, is correctly used.

libharfbuzz and libfreetype are compiled almost the same way, and share the `prepare_each.sh` script, so they are correctly located in the `BUILTDIR` directory before compiling libass.

Last note : I have temporarily deactivated SIP, so I do not have troubles with environment variables starting with `DYLD_`being discarded.

Comment: @RichardBarber no it's not. The correct way is to make the linker use the right library through flags like `-L` and `-l`.

Comment: My guess is that autoconf emits `pkg-config` lookups and that those take precedence over attempting to just link to a library and seeing whether it exists. If that is the case, then there should be env vars that let you override this, like `libfreetype_CFLAGS` (for includes) and `libfreetype_LIBS` (for `-L` and `-l`).

Comment: Why not send the compiler flags instead of via the --libdir directive?

Comment: @Siguza I have tried export FREETYPE_CFLAGS="-L$BUILTDIR/libfreetype.dylib"
export FREETYPE_LIBS="-L$BUILTDIR/libfreetype.dylib", and also export FREETYPE_CFLAGS="-L$BUILTDIR"
export FREETYPE_LIBS="-L$BUILTDIR", still the same. But the .pc file still contains libdir=/usr/local/lib

Comment: @RichardBarber I just add all the means possible until at least there is a change. Once the result is correct, I will try to optimize by removing unused things.

Comment: @Pierre did you make sure that these variables actually show up in the generated `./configure` script? Because usually the part before the underscore is lowercase...